# positioning images around text using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Doing a website recreation and trying to use bootstrap to do it. I ran into a problem of trying to position an image to the right of some text near the right edge of the web page.

Using margin-top and margin-right moves the picture how I want but using margin-bottom seems to have no effect... which is what I need. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here's a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/gkunthara/pen/eRXmoP

And releveant code:

HTML

```
<div class="second-content">

    <h2 class="second-header"> Bond Back Guarantee</h2>
    <p class="second-header-p text-left"> Moving homes in Sydney is 
stressful enough. With our end of lease cleaning service, getting your bond back has never been easier. Rest assured knowing that your real estate agent or landlord will accept your cleaning. If not, 
    just notify us within 72 hours and we'll gladly return to reclean any 
    problem areas - free of charge.</p>
    <img class="first-pic pull-right gap-right" src="firstpic.png">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.second-content .first-pic {

width: 30%;
border: solid black;
margin-right: 100px;
margin-bottom: 50px; /* no effect /*

}
```

EDIT: updated codepen link just showing relevant code

Comment: Did you know that you can post HTML/CSS/JS within Stack Overflow?

Comment: From looking at the code pen you've posted, it's not immediately clear which part is the problem. What I suggest is creating an example from scratch that demonstrates the issues. The very act of creating that example can help you solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the codepen showcasing what my issue is if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `pull-left` class to your `second-header-p`.

```css
.second-content {
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 20px;
}


.second-content .second-header {
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #3498DB;
}

.second-content .second-header-p {
    width: 65%;
    font-size: 120%;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.second-content .first-pic {

    width: 30%;
    border: solid black;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <title> End of Lease Cleaning in Sydney</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
  
    <div class="second-content">
        
        <h2 class="second-header"> Bond Back Guarantee</h2>
        <p class="second-header-p pull-left"> Moving homes in Sydney is stressful enough. With our end of lease cleaning service, getting your bond back has never been easier. Rest assured knowing that your real estate agent or landlord will accept your cleaning. If not, 
        just notify us within 72 hours and we'll gladly return to reclean any 
        problem areas - free of charge.</p>
        <img class="first-pic pull-right gap-right" src="https://thumb.ibb.co/iBF9Ea/firstpic.png" alt="firstpic" border="0">
    
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahh this does the trick. Why use pull-left and how come text-left seems to change things??

Comment: pull-left will float the complete block to left, whereas text-left is different it will align the text to left side.

Comment: i gotcha. Any idea as to why margin-bottom doesn't move the image up?

Comment: p is a block level element it will occupy completed width, even if you give width as 50% it wont allow other elements to come into its line unless until you make it to inline or inline-block element or float it to left. Here p occupied complete width and image has gone to new line. margin has nothing to do with it.

Comment: That makes sense. If I wanted to move the image up a little bit, if the margin has nothing to do with it, how would I go about moving it?

Comment: try giving negative margin-top, but thats not recommended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149191/discussion-between-brownmamba-and-supraja-ganji).

Answer (score 2):

As per your codepen you wanted image after text then need to add

**float:left in this class second-header-p text-left**.

```
.second-header-p.text-left{
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I add some  section for your code. `float:left and float:right` help to do your task well.

```
<body>
    <div class="second-content">
        <div class="sec">
            <h2 class="second-header"> Bond Back Guarantee</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="sec">
            <p class="second-header-p text-left"> Moving homes in Sydney is stressful enough. With our end of lease cleaning service, getting your bond back ha
                s never been easier. Rest assured knowing that your real estate agent or landlord will accept your cleaning.
                If not, just notify us within 72 hours and we'll gladly return to reclean any problem areas - free of charge.</p>
            <img class="first-pic pull-right gap-right" src="https://thumb.ibb.co/iBF9Ea/firstpic.png" alt="firstpic" border="0">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
.second-content {
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
}
.second-content .second-header {
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #3498DB;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
.second-content .second-header-p {
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float:left;
}
.second-content .first-pic {

    width: 30%;
    border: solid black;
    float:right;
}
.sec{
  width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using bootstrap then use this code:

`<html>`
`<head>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">`
`</script>`

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">`
`</script>`

`</head>`
`<body>`

`<section class="second-content">`

`<div class="col-md-8">`
`<h2 class="second-header"> Bond Back Guarantee</h2>`
`<p class="second-header-p text-left"> Moving homes in Sydney is stressful enough. With our end of lease cleaning service, getting your bond back has never been easier. Rest assured knowing that your real estate agent or landlord will accept your cleaning. If not, just notify us within 72 hours and we'll gladly return to reclean any problem areas - free of charge.</p>`
`</div>`

`<div class="col-md-4">`
`<img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/iBF9Ea/firstpic.png" />`
`</div>`

`</section>`

`</body>`
`</html>`